# How to switch functions for buttons in Tkinter?

Tags: python, tkinter, logic

So I want to make a program where when I click the button it should do make the text box have word wrap, but when I click on the button again it should reverse or switch it so that there is no word wrap.

Here is my code so far:

```
from tkinter import *


root = Tk()
root.geometry("600x600")

textBox = Text(root, width=500, height=500, wrap="none")

def doSomething():
    textBox.configure(wrap="word")
    # When I click it twice the wrap="none"

button = Button(root, text="Click Here", command=doSomething)
button.pack()


root.mainloop()
```

So when I click on the button it should change the wrap to word, but when I click it again it should change the wrap to none. So how would I do that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just change your function to:

```
def doSomething():
    if textBox.cget("wrap") == "none":
        textBox.configure(wrap="word")
    elif textBox.cget("wrap") =="word":
        textBox.configure(wrap="none")
```

Comment: Thanks that really helped + it works, is there also a way to add a checkmark when there is word wrap.

Comment: Just like a simple checkmark to show that word wrap is on. And when word wrap is set to none the checkmark should disappear.

Comment: I think you'd have to use images for that. You can create a label containing an image and when the button is clicked you can place that image on the screen using grid() and when clicked again you can remove it using grid_forget()

Answer (score 0):

You can use a `StringVar()` from tkinter.

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
from tkinter import *

root = Tk()
root.geometry("600x600")
var_button = StringVar()
var_button.set("word")

textBox = Text(root, width=500, height=500, wrap="none")

def doSomething():
    if var_button.get() == "word":       
        var_button.set("none")
        # When I click it twice the wrap="none"
    else:        
        textBox.configure(wrap="word")
        var_button.set("word") 
    print(f'textBox {var_button.get()}')

button = Button(root, text="Click Here", command=doSomething)
button.pack()
```